# Using ViewPager, how to disable swipe in gmaps fragment?

Tags: android, google-maps, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I am using some Fragments, FragmentActivity, ViewPager... I can swipe from a fragment to another.  In one fragment I have a gmaps fragment and I can't navigate in it, it will swipe to the next/previous fragment.
I wonder if it's possible (I'm pretty sure it is!) to disable swipe within the gmap fragment.  The fragment is not full screen so maybe swipe would be disable when we are inside it?

ViewPagerAdapter.java

```
public class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
    private Context _context;

    public ViewPagerAdapter(Context context, FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);  
        _context=context;

        }
    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        Fragment f = new Fragment();
        switch(position){
        case 0:
            f=LayoutOne.newInstance(_context);  
            break;
        case 1:
            f=LayoutTwo.newInstance(_context);  
            break;
        case 2:
            f=LayoutTree.newInstance(_context); 
            break;
        }
        return f;
    }
    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 3;
    }

}
```

ViewPagerStyle1Activity.java

```
public class ViewPagerStyle1Activity extends FragmentActivity {
    private ViewPager _mViewPager;
    private ViewPagerAdapter _adapter;
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        setUpView();
        setTab();
    }
    private void setUpView(){       
     _mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewPager);
     _adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getApplicationContext(),getSupportFragmentManager());
     _mViewPager.setAdapter(_adapter);
     _mViewPager.setCurrentItem(0);


    }
    private void setTab(){
            _mViewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new OnPageChangeListener(){

                        @Override
                        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int position) {}
                        @Override
                        public void onPageScrolled(int arg0, float arg1, int arg2) {}
                        @Override
                        public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                            switch(position){
                            case 0:
                                findViewById(R.id.first_tab).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                                findViewById(R.id.second_tab).setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                                findViewById(R.id.third_tab).setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                                break;

                            case 1:
                                findViewById(R.id.first_tab).setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                                findViewById(R.id.second_tab).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                                findViewById(R.id.third_tab).setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                                break;
                            case 2:
                                findViewById(R.id.first_tab).setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                                findViewById(R.id.second_tab).setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                                findViewById(R.id.third_tab).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                                break;
                            }
                        }

                    });

    }
}
```

LayoutTree.java

```
public class LayoutTree extends Fragment {
    private GoogleMap map;


    public static Fragment newInstance(Context context) {
        LayoutTree f = new LayoutTree();    

        return f;
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        ViewGroup root = (ViewGroup) inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_tree, null);  
        map = ((SupportMapFragment ) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
        return root;
    }

}
```

layout_tree.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:gravity="center|center"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:layout_width="290dp"
        android:layout_height="465dp"
        class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Don't know if bumping if allowed, but...